# No se ejecuta mi metodo Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Quiero llamar un metodo de otra clase que muestra una pantalla, el problema es que al tratar de llamarlo desde otra clase no hace nada.

lo hago de esta manera ejemplo:

```
NameClase *c = [[NameClase alloc]init];
[c metodo];
```

o

```
[[c init]metodo];
```

pero no se muestra la pantalla a que se debe ayuda.
y la pantalla que quiero mostrar si funciona.

Comment: puedes postear el codigo relativo a tu función metodo?, o ya lo has solucionado?

Comment: @ReinierMelian ya lo e solucionado gracias y la manera en que lo llamo de esa manera esta bien de echo

Answer (score 0):

Es importante que al crear tu método en tu Main, además hagas en el Header la declaración de ese método, para que pueda ser llamado al instanciar tu objeto en otras clases.

Guia:
https://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-objective-c-and-swift-together-ios-apps

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Header solo agregas la referencia de tu metodo asi

- (void) method;

De esta manera ya puedes llamar tu método al instanciar tu objeto con otras clases.